# How could I change path of electron storages(cache, crashpad, etc)

Tags: javascript, electron

I have been developing an app using electron, and I am trying to make it as portable as possible (and easily accessible to app data).

So I'm wondering if it's possible to change the paths of where electron stores the data to something like documents or even inside the app's folder (instead of %appdata%)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your Electron application portable, especially between operating systems, you should use the operating system default paths accessible by Electron, such as the users `home` directory, `documents` directory or better still your applications `appData` directory.

See Electrons [`app.getPath(name)`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/app#appgetpathname) and [`app.setPath(name, path)`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/app#appsetpathname-path) methods for more information.

> Note: It is a bad idea to store any form of data directly within the applications folder. Whilst "relative" referencing the data may be possible, an application update will overwrite (IE: delete) any data stored within.

Comment: thank you so much, I did not realise this was possible with setPath